# Adding windows to exterior entry doors

Tags: windows

Bought a home with two solid wood entry doors which result in a dark entry foyer

Anyone aware of a company making window inserts that can be installed in entry doors?

I'd hate to buy new doors to replace the current ones.

Thanks for your help

Comment: where on the Planet are you. If in USA ?

Comment: How are the doors constructed? Post some pictures?

Comment: I have put Windows into doors , make sure to get tempered glass (that is required in my area).

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of places where you can get door glass inserts. Big Box stores such as HDepot and others ..

search term Door Glass Inserts

You are going to invest in labor and also it might cost you similar pricing for a new door.

Answer (score 0):

I call those glass door inserts , “relites “ or “relights “.

I’d call a local custom cabinet shop.

Email them a pic and some dimensions, and they can give you a quote...without you hauling it in...